# Convert IQueryable to List<T> type

Tags: linq

I just performed a query with `LINQ` from the DAL and got a collection of a record with imbedded `ILIST` objects like the following

```
string name
date   startDate
date  endDate
ILIST<MyType> ImbeddedList (this contains more columns like recordID, sentDate, dueDate)
```

I need to return a `LIST<T>` back to the grid to be bounded.

I am having some problems with writing the `LINQ` statement to filter out the `IQueryable` collection object.

In my statement below:

```
IQueryable<All_DATA> cases = dalObject.GetData();
var mylist = cases.Select(s => {s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate,s.ImbeddedList????}).ToList();
```

When I get to the ImbeddedList, which is returned from the dalObject, the intellsense does not show the fields in the ImbeddedList. How can I correctly write the `LINQ` statement to filter for more fields in the ImbeddedList object?

Comment: If my soln helped u then accept d answer or ask if anything else needed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understand what you can do is

**For fetching complete list from `ImbeddedList`**

```
var mylist = cases.Select(s => {s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, s.ImbeddedList}).ToList();
```

**And for fetching individual field from `ImbeddedList`**

```
var mylist = cases.SelectMany(s => s.ImbeddedList)
                  .Select(IItem => { IItem.Field1, IItem.Field2 }).ToList();
```

For more information please refer:

1. [The Linq SelectMany Operator](http://www.codethinked.com/the-linq-selectmany-operator)
2. [LINQ - Get all items in a List within a List?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3267079/468718)
3. [Using LINQ, select list of objects inside another list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3934583/468718)
4. [Use Google Search: "linq select list within list"](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?q=linq%20select%20list%20within%20list)

Comment: How can you combined both of them? Thanks for helping.

Comment: For that u need to select single record from ImbeddedList n then get the field u need n if u need multiple fields on that single element then ...

Comment: .... I think u should check what is OUTER APPLY & CROSS APPLY in SQL query.. N how to use it in LINQ.

Comment: 1 more thing if u are not sure what will b linq query for what u need then please provide the SQL query (if any) n so we can help u or otherwise use linqpad for converting vice versa..

Comment: Harsh, I am still confused. From your example, i see that you can get the selected fields from each object to one list. And the selected fields from the imbedded list. My question is how do I combined them. If I get 50 records from the IQueryable object, which contains fields from the object and additional fields from the imbedded list, how do I do a select in LINQ to select only those fields from the object and imbedded list in one statement and populate a new var mylist object? thanks for helping.